# Jquery, finding the type of a selector - howto?

Tags: jquery, detection, object-type

I need a way to determine if a returned object is a textarea (for example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('selector').is('textarea');
```

Or:

```
alert($('selector')[0].type);
```

Comment: and with  $("textarea.foo"), jquery will return only textarea's with the class "foo". It is no detection like the given answer, but a more precise way of selection

Comment: @Justus Romijn: Sure it depends on selector specified.

Comment: your answer is bulls-eye, I just wanted to point out that css-selection (which jQuery uses) is totally awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("selector").attr('type')
```